# Given lists of length M and N, how to get a list of length M*N with all possible pairs

Tags: python

Suppose we have two lists `a` and `b`:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
```

Is there a quick operation that will return the list of tuples `[(1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4)]`?

Comment: look up itertools.product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension does it:

```
[(i,j) for i in a for j in b]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4]
>>> [(i,j)  for i in a for j in b]
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
list(itertools.product(a, b))
```

This is useful if you have several lists, or a variable number of lists.

For example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4]
>>> c = [5, 6]
>>> list(itertools.product(a, b, c))
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The function [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) will do the trick:

```
In [41]: a, b = [1, 2], [3, 4]

In [42]: from itertools import product

In [43]: list(product(a, b))
Out[43]: [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

It is important to point out that you need to invoke the built-in function `list()` to convert the iterator returned by `product` into a list.

As a side note, if your goal is that of computing the product of a list with itself, you may find it handy to use the optional `repeat` keyword argument:

```
In [46]: list(product(a, repeat=3))
Out[46]: 
[(1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (2, 1, 1),
 (2, 1, 2),
 (2, 2, 1),
 (2, 2, 2)]
```